# Is there a difference between creating a variable and creating a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to understand whether a Python `for` loop would call an action multiple times if you put the action in the loop directly.

For example, take these two similar functions.

a)

```
def get_cat(breed_name):
    from requests import get
    from json import loads
    api_key = "***"
    limit = 5
    params = {"breed_name": breed_name,
              "api_key": api_key,
              "limit": limit}
    url = "https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search"
    response = get(
        url=url,
        params=params)
    cats = loads(response.content)
    for cat in cats:
        print(cat["url"])
```

b)

```
def get_cat(breed_name):
    from requests import get
    from json import loads
    api_key = "***"
    limit = 5
    params = {"breed_name": breed_name,
              "api_key": api_key,
              "limit": limit}
    url = "https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search"
    for cat in loads(get(url=url, params=params).content):
        print(cat["url"])
```

Personally, I feel that separating out the variables as in a) is easier to read, so I always do this. This also feels like a more standard way to write Python.

You will note that in b) the `response` and `cats` vars have been smushed together in the declaration of the `for` loop. Would `loads(get(url=url, params=params).content)` be called multiple times or just the once?

Comment: It might be a bit tricky to say. Is `loads()` a generator that uses `yield` or a more traditional iterator that might return say a `list`? Depending on how you answer that the interpretation of called once vs called multiple times could be different. Though from a 50k meter view, `loads()` is called "once"

Comment: Would `get` be called more than once in b)?